# Update Term Store with external database value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, term-store

I need to update my term store with information from an external data source a Database of some sort like SQL server Database. So as soon as information is available from the DB table, the term store needs to be updated as well.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Task Scheduler and PowerShell...!

Comment: Powershell sounds awesome. May you please provide me with the resources I am not that excellent with Powershell :)

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't got any good stubs in my repository - but maybe this link will get you going? http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2015/04/sharepoint-add-terms-to-termstore-via-powershell/